# how to implement sso in my spring application using saml?

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, saml

I am looking for saml integration with spring application. I have read some of documents but mostly all are based on spring boot application. Can someone help me to integrate saml in spring application for sso Or suggest the good document guide for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to take advantage of the Spring Security SAML project:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml

There is a sample project in the repository that demonstrates how one may be able to use the library. It's located here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/master/sample

Note that the current official release of this extension builds against OpenSAML v2, and there is a `develop` branch that is in the process of updating to OpenSAML v3. You are welcome to try and see how that might work for you.

There is also the pac4j project which likewise, allows you build SAML2 SP support into your app and integrate with an identity provider:

http://www.pac4j.org/3.6.x/docs/clients/saml.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but none of from these are exactly what i am looking for.