# SSO implementation in Spring MVC application using Saml and Ldap

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap, single-sign-on, saml

I have a spring MVC application[Saas] implemented in place which has a common login module.Now I want to implement SSO in that application using Saml and ldap.
i have implemented some demo using ssocircle as a IDP. i am stuck at how to use saml and ldap in existing application for sso. and what IDP exactly meant for?

can someone guide me how to do that? Any Guide and clarification will be Much appreciated .

Thanks In Advance.

is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Did you work through the starting points at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54909095/3976662? Summarize your experiences in the question. Consider also the Spring SAML V2 guide at https://github.com/Endeios/samlv2app

Comment: yes i am gone through from the points. but i am still not able to find a proper solution. My MVC application runs on a diffrent domain so which is the better way to implement SSO in this case?

Comment: You can use any SAMLv2 compliant IdP, you just need to configure the IdP meta data.

LDAP does not provide SSO, but SAML is a standards-based way to achieve web-based SSO without the need for cookies. It does not matter in which (cookie-)domains the IdP or the SP (your app) are located.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr can you  provide any guide or example related to it?